# Prisma generic return type for select function

Tags: nestjs, typescript-generics, prisma

I have the function below:

```
async getUserById(
    userId: string, 
    args: Prisma.UserArgs,
): Promise<User>{    
    const findUniqueArgs: Prisma.UserFindUniqueArgs = {
      where: {
        publicId: userId,
      },
      ...args
    }

    return await this.prisma.user.findUnique(findUniqueArgs);
  }
```

I would like to ask that in Prisma when using Typescript do we need to define the return type for function. If yes how we can make generic type that the return type will based on the args I pass to function

I expected that when I try to execute getUserById with the args is {select: {email: true, id: true}} the return type only have that field when I use dot on the result